# Why does it suffice to prove that $\sup A+\sup B\leq\sup(A+B)+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ to prove that $\sup A+\sup B\leq \sup(A+B)$

Tags: real-analysis

Problem 13 of chapter 8 on page 141 of Spivak Calculus, 4th edition says

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two nonempty sets of numbers which are bounded above, and let $A+B$ denote the set of all numbers $x+y$ with $x$ in $A$ and $y$ in $B$. Prove that $\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B$. Hint: The inequality $\sup(A+B)\leq\sup A+\sup B$ is easy. Why? To prove that $\sup A+\sup B\leq \sup(A+B)$ it suffices to prove that $\sup A+\sup B\leq\sup(A+B)+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$; begin by choosing $x$ in $A$ and $y$ in $B$ with $\sup A-x<\epsilon/2$ and $\sup B-y<\epsilon/2$.

My question is

> Why does it suffice to prove that $\sup A+\sup B\leq\sup(A+B)+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ to prove that $\sup A+\sup B\leq \sup(A+B)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and suppose that

(*) $a \le b + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$.

Then we have $a \le b$.

Proof: suppose to the contrary that $a>b$. Then $\epsilon:=(a-b)/2>0$.

From (*) we get: $a \le b+(a-b)/2$. It follows that $a \le b$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sup A+\sup B > \sup(A+B)$, then for some $\epsilon > 0$ (anything less than $\sup A+\sup B -\sup(A+B)$ will do), $\sup A+\sup B > \sup(A+B) +\epsilon$.